# Nginx not updating webpages. Using Termux

Tags: html, nginx, termux

I am trying to run a small website from my tablet with Termux and Ngnix. The nginx.conf file has been properly configured, and the webpages have been placed in the correct folder. The problem is that when I make changes to the html code, the nginx server doesn't seem to want to update with the new changes.

For example, I had a thumbnail image that would open in a new tab for viewing at full size when clicked. I later changed the html code so the same thumbnail image would open up a page on the site with related text info. I made sure to stop the server before applying any changes to my code, and then restarting the server after the appropriate changes were made. Unfortunately, the server keeps displaying the pages *before* the changes. It's like the original pages are stuck somewhere in the server's "memory" and don't want to update. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? This is getting really frustrating.

Thank you in advance to any who can help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the issue was with the browser and not Nginx. I cleared the data from the browser, restarted, and haven't had any issues since. Strange, but it worked.